# Why Android Device Monitor Is Not Working In My PC?

Tags: java, android

The screenshot of my window is given below:

[image]

Comment: Even we don't know either!

Comment: Please try to reset adb, possibly will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the device controller at the android ADV's panel.